# Tomcat 7 records all logs into catalina.out but not into log4j2 defined files

Tags: java, log4j, tomcat7, classpath, web.xml

Before converting my application into the web app. Log4j was recording logs in the correct log files (info.log and debug.log) which I've defined in the **log4j2.xml**.

But when I've changed my application to web.app, all logs now records into the **catalina.out** file in the servlet container (**tomcat 7**).
After deploying application log4j2 creates these log file, but they remain empty and all logs goes to catalina.out file.

Could you suggest what I am doing wrong.

In **web.xml**, I've added necessary configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <display-name>project-service</display-name>

    <!-- Support for Spring -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath*:applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfiguration</param-name>
        <param-value>log4j2.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>


</web-app>
```

**log4j2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace" strict="true" name="XMLConfigTest"
               packages="">         

    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n"/>
        </Console>

        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFileDebug" fileName="/local/deploy/logs/debug.log"
                                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/project-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
                                 immediateFlush="false"
                                 append="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <RollingRandomAccessFile name="RollingRandomAccessFile" fileName="/local/deploy/logs/info.log"
                                 filePattern="logs/$${date:yyyy-MM}/project-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}-%i.log.gz"
                                 immediateFlush="false"
                                 append="false">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy/>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="250 MB"/>
            </Policies>
        </RollingRandomAccessFile>
        <!--<Async name="AsyncConsole">-->
        <!--<AppenderRef ref="Console"/>-->
        <!--</Async>-->
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root  level="TRACE">
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFileDebug" level="DEBUG"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="RollingRandomAccessFile" level="INFO"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"  level="TRACE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

change fileName attribute from

fileName="/local/deploy/logs/info.log"

to something like this(whatever the path in ur case)

fileName="${sys:catalina.home}/logs/info.log"

if it writes in both catalina as well as in log file then refer this link

http://app-inf.blogspot.com/2012/10/java-util-logging-behaviour-in-tomcat.html